# Command line calculator with good hex support

Tags: osx, command-line, calculator

Is there a command line calculator that will let me do bit operations and has good support for hex. E.g. for operations like:

```
0xff << 3
(1 << 5) ^ 0x77
```

Bad solutions:

- `bc` - laughable support for hex
- Frink - might work, but it's a big java app and not easily installable through Brew etc.
- [radix-calc](https://github.com/goodell/radix-calc) - close to what I want, but I'd prefer a REPL, with support for variables etc.
- Python - too verbose for printing hex etc.

The software should work on a Mac and ideally be open source. Must support standard C operators, and ideally setting variables and printing them as hex.

Comment: Isn't OS X just a GUI over BSD? I'm not trying to start a flame war here with that "just". But, maybe a UNIX or even Linux tag might attract more answers, since it's a command line utility you are after.

Answer (score 0):

[PowerShell (PowerShell Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases/tag/v6.0.3) comes close to what you want. It's a REPL, supports hex, supports variables, supports defining functions. (It's more than a plain calculator, though!)

Shortcomings:

It supports the *functionality* of bitwise operators, but not with the C symbols - e.g., `<<` is `-shl`, `|` is `-bor`, and so on - see [Get-Help about_Arithmetic_Operators](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arithmetic_operators?view=powershell-6) for details.

Hex *output* is awkward and verbose; you'd pretty much have to do it as `"{0:X4}"-f (`*insert calculation here*`)`  (4 is the number of hex digits to use; you can use more or less as you choose) - but hex *input* is standard - `0x` followed by hex digits.

Comment: Not a terrible option. I feel like `radix-calc` is better. Maybe I'll just modify it to have a REPL.

Comment: @Timmmm - You consider this *not* a terrible option? How is this better than Python? Python uses C symbols and standard hex input; and hex output is achieved by simply using the `hex` function. Obviously Python has a REPL, variables, and functions. It's even already installed on your Mac.

Comment: Yeah after trying it Python does seem a better option.